# Isolating WordPress to a subfolder

Tags: htaccess, directory

I'm trying to isolate a wordpress installation on our site to a specific subfolder. I created a folder on our root site named `_wp` and placed all the wordpress files in there. I added the following rewrite rules to the htaccess in our root folder to allow permalinks within the wordpress installation to work properly.

```
# Wordpress
RewriteBase /_wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /_wp/index.php [L]
```

This allowed permalinks within the subfolder to work, but it is also allowing requests for files outside the `_wp` folder to forward to the wordpress site. For example, the following page on my wordpress site:

http://www.mysite.com/_wp/mypage

can also be accessed by the following URL:

http://www.mysite.com/mypage

I don't want this to happen. I want to isolate all access to the wordpress site by requiring the `_wp` prefix. Does anybody know how I would modify the htaccess above to allow this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your WP site to function completely in subfolder, just set it up there as usual (including `.htaccess`) and do not add any directives to the root.

Setup of `.htaccess` in root, while WP is in subfolder, is only necessary if you want to have core files (and so admin area) there, but have site itself be root-based. As per [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) instructions in Codex.

Comment: Thanks, it was as easy as that! I just placed the above .htaccess rules in the _wp folder, instead of the root.